# How do I hide my CV and story from bots?

Tags: support, profile-page

In the past it had option to [hide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81950/can-i-prevent-my-career-page-to-be-indexed-by-search-engines) my CV from bots. It placed a `noindex` and `nofollow` tags in the meta. Thus my CV page disappeared from Google search results. Unfortunately it looks like my profile has reappeared in Google search results.

Comment: You can't hide from bots. [They are everywhere](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXnL7sdElno), and they can grab you with their metal claws.

Comment: Why are you putting your CV online if you don't want people to contact you or your information visible publicly? make your CV a pdf download on your website and only display information you want internationally and easily available. noindex and nofollow are more like requests than guarantees in how bots follow them

Comment: @KaranHarshWardhan `noindex` doesn't prevent people visiting the page. Big search engines respect `noindex`.

Comment: so what is the goal here? people should be able to find CV via link but not via google?

Comment: @KaranHarshWardhan, the point is privacy. Why you are so dissatisfied? It is optional. It was already implemented.

Comment: i think there is a language gap here that i can't comprehend. good luck!

Comment: @ilhan In my experience, it is customary on Stack Overflow to ask direct to-the-point questions in comments, in order to get clarifications from the user asking the question. I'd recommend not assuming any mood or dissatisfaction load with a comment.

Comment: @Pac0, my answer is 8 years old https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81950/can-i-prevent-my-career-page-to-be-indexed-by-search-engines#comment200133_81950